# Hidden Web pages vulnerability

Tags: security, hidden

I have written an application using struts2 and tiles running on tomcat 7. The core impact vulnerability scan came back with "Hidden Pages Vulnerability - Backup Web Pages" listing around 5 links. All these links should be available to the end user so that they can use the functionality. These are not pointing any files or directories. But as per the company policy ?? the vulnerability report should be clean without anything listed. I don't know what this vulnerability is all about as these are required links for user. 
Can someone give me some pointers ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Problem is I don't know what to fix. Can you explain what is hidden page vulnerability / backup webpages vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden/backup pages vulnerability refers to the pages in the web application that are found to be unreachable on having browsed the  web application completely.

Hidden page: It might be a page with some extra privileges added by the attacker (possibly the developer), as a backdoor. As it is no where linked in the web site, no one else would know about it(or that is what the attacker expects)

Backup page: For example, consider index.html has much more information added for debugging during development phase. Then a copy is saved as index.bkp in the same directory for future testing and extra code from index.html is removed. Now, though index.bkp is not directly linked in the website, an attacker can guess such pages and misuse them...
Backup pages may also result as some editors save intermediary files...

It is therefore required to ensure that all unused files are removed from the web container. If any page's backup is required, it has to be saved elsewhere, outside the web container.

This vulnerability detected by a vulnerability scanner can be a false positive​ in cases when, a page is reachable only after some specific criteria is met, which the scanner is unaware of or is incapable of. Example: pages protected by CAPTCHA.

In such cases of false positives, you have to be aware that the **vulnerability scanner couldn't reach your page and therefore your scan is incomplete**.

To overcome this issue, most of the scanners provision the user to help it crawl the website by providing appropriate inputs...